# Black band appeared on display

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, display

I suddenly have a black band at the left side of my screen (see screenshot below). Dual monitor setup, Xubuntu, see details below.

- When setting the primary display to my laptop then the black band appears there.
- The black band does not appear on the startup screen.
- Rebooting, changing display configurations, wallpaper etc does not solve the problem.
- The black band occurs in all programs (browser, LibreOffice, etc.).
- I did not change anything in the setup of my computer; the problem just appeared suddenly.

---

```
henk@henk-W330AU ~> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Resolution  2560x1440 pixels
Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Version 1.18.4
Vendor  Intel Open Source Technology Center
Renderer    Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
Version 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
Direct Rendering    Yes
```

[image]

Comment: click and remove it? try clicking on its right edge.

Comment: Thanks! I can move it, and lock it. "It" behaves like a panel, so remove panel. Thanks again...